# Microsoft Access Clear Some of the Data in Multiple Rows in a Subform

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a form with a subform.  The subform has multiple rows.  The following fields are in the subform (control, status, validationDate, notes). I would like to be able to clear all of the data in the status, validationDate and notes field, but be able to maintain the data in the control field.  I was able to find the code below to help, but it only removes data I want from one row at a time instead of all of the rows. I have to select the next row and click the button again in order to remove the data I want.

Private Sub Clear_One_Row_Click()

Me.Kontrol_Subform.Form.notes = ""
Me.Kontrol_Subform.Form.status = ""
Me.Kontrol_Subform.Form.validationDate = ""

End Sub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcW34.png)